# Return a String value from my popup menu in MatLab

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I am developing a simple GUI with MATLAB (guide) with a pop up menu in it. In order to establish a connection through a serial port.

```
function sendLog_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
set(handles.popupmenuSerialPort,'String', {'''COM1''','''COM2''','''COM3''','''COM4'''});
...
```

I would like to get the selected value in this way:

```
serialPortList = get(handles.popupmenuSerialPort,'String');
    serialPortValue = get(handles.popupmenuSerialPort,'Value');
    serialPort = serialPortList(serialPortValue);
    disp('serialPort ' + serialPortValue);
```

But I get an error message on disp function:

> Undefined function 'plus' for input arguments of type 'cell'.
>
> Invalid PORT specified.

How could I get the chosen value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate to plow through 2 answers that are clearly not bad, but here the devil is in the details.  Yes, you cannot concatenate strings in MATLAB with the `+` operator, but the first red flag in your question is that your error message indicates a `cell` as one of the arguments to `+`.  **Note that `disp` has not even thrown an error at this point, it was `+`.**  This leads me to believe that your code is actually `disp('serialPort ' + serialPort);` not `disp('serialPort ' + serialPortValue);` since `serialPortList` is a `cell` array.  Was this a typo?

So, by indexing it like `serialPort = serialPortList(serialPortValue);` you get a single cell in `serialPort`, which would not work with proper string concatenation or `disp`.  The correction here is to use the curly braces (`{}`).

Together with valid string concatenation,

```
>> serialPort = serialPortList{serialPortValue};
>> disp(['serialPort ' serialPort])
serialPort 'COM3'
```

The single quotes are in the string because of how you set the strings with `set(handles.popupmenuSerialPort,'String',...`, so if you want to strip that, you can use `strrep(serialPort,'''','')`.

Note that you can also use `fprintf` if you are more comfortable with that style of string formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use '+' to combine strings in matlab.
you can do:

```
disp(['serialPort',num2str(serialPortValue)]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try array concatenation :
`disp(['SerialPort : ' serialPortValue]);`